# ListView two way compiled binding (x:Bind)

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, binding, windows-10

I want to display several names, and I want them to be editable.
So I used an ObservableColection, and bind it to a ListView with the new x:Bind feature.

Here's my XAML:

```
    <ListView>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Players}">
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate xmlns:model="using:Flechette.Model"  x:DataType="model:Player">
                <TextBox Text="{x:Bind Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

And my code behind:

```
public sealed partial class GameSettingsPage : Page
{
    ViewModel.GameSettingsViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    public GameSettingsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContextChanged += (s, e) => ViewModel = DataContext as ViewModel.GameSettingsViewModel;
    }
}
```

The problem is that TwoWay binding failed to compile, I get the error **CS1061 'WeakReference' does not contain a definition for 'LostFocus' and no extension method 'LostFocus' accepting a first argument of type 'WeakReference' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Can you show the full xaml.  Are you doing x:Bind on the LostFocus event?

Comment: [The full XAML code](http://pastebin.com/GL4vZn38)
As you can see, I want to edit the elements in the ListView. It is working properly with classic binding,  but not with x:Bind

Comment: If you change the TwoWay bind to OneWay, do you get the issue?

Comment: No, it works with OneWay

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a problem in the preview version of Windows 10 SDK. Given the following code:

**MainPage.xaml:**

```
     <ListView x:Name="Players">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Player">
                <TextBox Text="{x:Bind Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs:**

```
    private ObservableCollection<Player> players = new ObservableCollection<Player>();
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        this.players.Add(new Player());
        this.players.Add(new Player());
        this.players.Add(new Player());
        this.players.Add(new Player());
        this.players.Add(new Player());

        this.Players.ItemsSource = players;
    }
```

**Player.cs:**

```
public class Player : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            if (value == name) return;
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

The compilation and app works and provides the expected behavior:

[image: Working app]